# Discord py - How to check if creating date is below 10 minutes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, discord.py, python-datetime

how can I check if a created server invite is below 10 minutes? I tried to make a list that prints every invite that's created below 10 minutes ago, but it doesn't print anything.

I tried:

```py
invites = await ctx.guild.invites()
for invite in invites:
    if (time.time() - invite.created_at.timestamp()) < 600:
        print(invite)
```

I added:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_invite_create(invite):
    print(invite.created_at.timestamp())
    print(time.time())
    print(time.time() - invite.created_at.timestamp())
```

and that was the results from the prints (fresh created invite):

```
1619006499.447825
1619013699.5136192
7200.065812826157
```

Comment: Maybe because you have no invites? That's the only thing I can see potentially wrong with this code.

Comment: I created many invites. I noticed that a created invite with this code (except the `< 600` part) gets a timestamp of 7200, i don't understand why.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how `discord.py` works, but I would try printing out each invite's `invite.created_at.timestamp()` and the current `time.time()` at that print for debugging, to see if that is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`discord.Guild.invites()` method](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.invites) returns a list of [`discord.Invite` objects](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Invite). Each `discord.Invite` object has an [attribute `created_at`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Invite.created_at), which returns the time which the invite was created at as a [`datetime.datetime` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime). This is different than `time.time()`, which is simply a float. So, you should use [`datetime.datetime.now()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) to get the current time as a `datetime.datetime` object.

```py
import datetime

invites = await ctx.guild.invites()
for invite in invites:
    if (datetime.datetime.now() - invite.created_at).total_seconds() < 600:
        print(invite)
```

Alternatively, you could use [`datetime.timedelta()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) to compare the differences in time.

```py
for invite in await ctx.guild.invites():
    if datetime.datetime.now() - invite.created_at < datetime.timedelta(minutes=10):
        print(invite)
```